# Accessing multiple shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I basically want to be able to have multiple SharedPreferences files for my app. The names of these will be based off of a string entered by the user. Then when the user wants to restore, I want to create a popup that will allow them to pick from all available SharedPreferences files. Is there a way to see what SharedPreferences files are in the directory? Or is there a better way to store this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could save a csv list of SharedPreferences as a SharedPreference...

But I think if you are going to have multiple configurations, better approaches would be either a small [SqliteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) or ".ini" files in the [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Comment: Is there anyway to easily then read and parse through the file you store to internal storage, like the key/value pairs of SharedPrefs? Or is it just like split on new line and save, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you insisted on using SharedPreferences as the storage mechanism, what you could do is use the default shared preferences (get it with  `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`) to store a list of the preference files created (using something like the `putStringSet` method at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29). You can then retrieve them later and generate the popup list.